# How to fix python: not found error when I already installed python

Tags: python, shell, conda

I want to run a shell script in conda, but it shows the errors like

```
./run_augment_data.sh: 9: python: not found
```

but when I type

```
type python python3
```

the shell gives me an existing path.

```
python is /home/rd142857/anaconda3/envs/test_env/bin/python
python3 is /home/rd142857/anaconda3/envs/test_env/bin/python3
```

I tried changing `python` into `python3`, the above error disappears but the new error is

```
/usr/bin/python3: Error while finding module specification for 'torch.distributed.launch' (ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'torch')
```

I notice that the python the script want to use is not the python in my conda. So I add the following sentence to the top of the script

```
#!/home/rd142857/anaconda3/envs/test_env/bin/python
```

then re-run the script, the new error is

```
File "/home/rd142857/grappa/grappa/./run_augment_data.sh", line 6
    rm -r $LOGDIR
          ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

I really don't know what to do now.

The full content of the shell script is

```
#export NGPU=2;
#CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES=0,1 python -u -m torch.distributed.launch --nproc_per_node=$NGPU finetuning_roberta.py --train_corpus data/augment_data.txt \
LOGDIR="grappa_logs_checkpoints/ssp/"
rm -r $LOGDIR
mkdir $LOGDIR

export NGPU=4;
python -u -m torch.distributed.launch --nproc_per_node=$NGPU finetuning_roberta.py --train_corpus data/augment_data.txt \
                                   --eval_corpus data/spider_dev_data_v2.txt \
                                   --train_eval_corpus data/spider_train_data_small_v2.txt \
                                   --bert_model roberta-large \
                                   --output_dir $LOGDIR/ \
                                   --do_train \
                                   --do_eval \
                                   --train_batch_size 12 \
                                   --max_seq_length 218 \
                                   --num_train_epochs 10 \
                                   > $LOGDIR/log.out
```

Comment: `rm -r $LOGDIR` That is a shell command.  Why are you using Python to run a shell command script?

Comment: Maybe there is an alias to python. At the shell type `alias` to see. Also, check the script to see if its redefining paths or python.

Comment: It would help to post a simple shell script demonstrating the problem. Perhaps just the shabange `#!/bin/sh` and then a line running `python --version`. Also, which OS you are using.

Answer (score 0):

The `rm -r $LOGDIR` implies that your script is a *shell* script, not a Python one, and so the shebang (top of the script) should be something like

**run_augment_data.sh**

```bash
#!/usr/bin/env bash -l
```

When trying to use a Python interpreter from a specific Conda environment, I recommend using `conda run`. Something like

```bash
conda run -n test_env python script.py
```

See `conda run --help`.